# TestNG execution halts between tests

Tags: selenium, testng-eclipse

I am refactoring a huge bunch of selenium tests and trying to execute them in testNG. The problem is test execution halts after each tests(eventually getting timedout) irrespective of the results.  When i do a browser refresh the tests continue. I am not sure what the problem is.

My tests are like this

```
@Test(groups = {" Portal - Page Login Tests"})
public void testPageLoginWithInvalidPwd() throws Exception{
    Assert.assertEquals( Login(GetWebDriver(...);
}

@Test(groups = {" Portal - Page Login Tests"})
public void testPageLoginWithValidPws() throws Exception{
    Assert.assertEquals( Login(...);
}
```

Here is my xml file

```
<suite name="test-single">
    <parameter name="Url" value="https:test.com" />
    <parameter name="Browser" value="firefox" />
    <test verbose="1" name="test">
        <classes>
            <class name="test.PageloginPage">
                <methods>
                    <include name="testPageLoginWithInvalidPwd"></include>
                    <include name="testPageLoginWithValidPws"></include>
                    </methods>
                </class>
        </classes>
```

Thanks in advance.

Stack Trace :
FAILED: testPageLoginWithValidPws
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout
  (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.119)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:32.194Z'
System info: host: '100206-PHY', ip: '10.1.208.242', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '9.0.4'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca..., userDataDir: C:\Users\KKULAN~1\AppData\L...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 64.0.3282.119, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: 0bb70fb5edb140fd90d7351ece634135
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:325)
    at k3g.edwebpageclasses.ELogin.loginToPortal(ELogin.java:269)
    at k3g.webpagefunctionality.Power.Login(Power.java:197)
    at k3g.ed.LoginPage.testPageLoginWithValidPws(LoginPage.java:152)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:571)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:707)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:979)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1028)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:996)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

Comment: You havn't shown us what you are expecting the _driver_ to do to find out the reason why it _eventually getting timedout_ . Show us your relevant code trials and HTML along with the entire error stack trace.

Comment: Thanks @DebanjanB. Control is not returning back after a get request ( getDriver().get(CommonURLs.LoginURL);) . I hope this issue is related to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=402. I am executing on chrome with all latest versions which i updated 2 days back and prior to update no issues. Probably i should give a try now with FF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded the browser and driver versions for 62 and 2.34 and issue is not seen